# DATASET_CANT_CLOSE error number 32 "Broken Pipe"

Tags: abap

I experienced an error in SAP ABAP which says DATASET_CANT_CLOSE with error number 32 (Broken Pipe). Question is: **what procedure triggered this kind of error?**

As far as I know, this error was triggered by:

`CLOSE DATASET dset`

But I can't reproduce the error since I don't know what procedure does trigger this kind of error.

This is the code I use:

```
method GENERATE_TXT_FILE.

  DATA :
        lwa_data TYPE t_line,
        lv_param TYPE sxpgcolist-parameters.

  "Upload File to Server
  *Open Dataset
  OPEN DATASET im_file_name FILTER 'dos2ux'
      FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.

  CLEAR lwa_data.

  LOOP AT it_data INTO lwa_data.

    CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS file_access_errors = 4
                        OTHERS = 8.
      TRANSFER lwa_data-lines TO im_file_name.
    ENDCATCH.

    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      CLEAR lwa_data.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
    CLEAR lwa_data.

  ENDLOOP.

  *Close Dataset
  CLOSE DATASET im_file_name.
```

Comment: Please add the complete code - at least the part that opens the dataset and closes it.

Comment: Added the complete open-close dataset codes.. Kindly help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have investigated through the background job log, it seems that the **current server** which run the background job haven't got mapped yet to the text file folder. Solution is to re-map the server to text file folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`FILTER` extension to `OPEN DATASET`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapopen_dataset_os_addition.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@) - which can be a **HUGE** security issue as well as raise loads of portability issues unless you know what you're doing, but that's not what the question is about. From the documentation:

> When the statement OPEN DATASET is executed, a process is started in
>   the operating system for the specified statement. When the file is
>   opened for reading, a channel (pipe) is linked with STDOUT of the
>   process, from which the data is read during file reading. The file
>   itself is linked with STDIN of the process. When the file is opened
>   for writing, a channel (pipe) is linked to STDIN of the process, to
>   which data is passed when writing. The output of the process is
>   diverted to this file.

In your case, the filter command probably decided to bail out - see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84813/what-makes-a-unix-process-die-with-broken-pipe) among many. Why is hard to investigate - you may have to go through various system logs to find out. If the problem really is some unmapped network folder, you could try switching to UNC paths.